# How to get checkbox value in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

```
<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" ID="customSwitches" />
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitches">Are You Admin?</label>                                   
</div>
```

The above code is from aspx file

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string username = txtUsername.Text;
        string password = txtPassword.Text;

        bool isAdmin = customSwitches.Checked;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I want to get the checkbox value
But I am getting an error on customSwitches.Checked;
Error: The 'customSwitches' doesnot exist in the current context.

Comment: It's unclear what the specific issue is. What about your code is not working?

Comment: I am getting an error on customSwitches.Checked;

Comment: The problem is you're mixing WebForms (`.aspx`) with MVC's Razor Tag Helpers (which can only be used in `.cshtml` files). Also, _why_ are you using WebForms in 2022?

Answer (score 2):

Your input with ID="customSwitches" is an html element and not an asp.net checkbox, and as it is missing the runat="server" tag you will not be able to access it by ID in the codebehind.

Try replacing it with an asp.net checkbox control like this:

```html
<asp:CheckBox ID="customSwitches" runat="server" CssClass="custom-control-input" />
```

Comment: I have add runat="server" in my input tag<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" runat="server" ID="customSwitches" />and it works for me btw thanks for the guidance

Answer (score 2):

To determine the value of a checkbox from a [code-behind class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/aspnet/development/code-behind-model#code-behind), the checkbox must be declared as a server-side control (`<asp:Checkbox>`) with `runat="server"` attribute instead of a pure HTML element (`<input>`):

`<asp:Checkbox id="customSwitches" runat="server" cssclass="custom-control-input" />`

Checkboxes don't return any value other than `true` or `false` for the `Checked` property.

Answer (score -2):

```
string CheckboxValue = false;
if(customSwitches.Checked)
{
CheckboxValue = true;
}
```